# What stat do I increase for a DPH Aegislash?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I need to EV train my Aegislash so he can become a massive damage per hitter. But, because of the Stance change, I don't know what stat to increase. I have heard results that he directly swaps his attack and defense, but I have heard other results where that it does not move EVs. I need some clarification before I continue Super Training.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it doesn't "swap" anything, the BSTs are changed but EVs and stat increases/decreases are left on the corresponding stat, just recalculated with the new BST in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EVs don't get swapped like that. The Base Stat of Aegislash gets swapped upon stance change and the final stats are recalculated upon swapping.

So, if you have 252 EVs in Atk during Shield Forme, you will still have 252 EVs in Atk during Sword Forme.

Comment: So I put all EVs into Attack for DPS?

Comment: @ShadowZorgon That will depend on your strategy. If you plan to hit as hard as possible on the physical side, then yes.

Comment: Okay, that clarifies things.

Comment: Aegislash actually works better as a Special Attacker, because the base stat is the same, the movepool is just as good if not better, and you're no longer susceptible to Intimidate or Burn ;)

Comment: @Zorgon the above comment from Niet is meant for you I believe.